# Combine negative lookahead and behind regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I would like a regex which will split a string at every `"."` except if the `"."` is preceded AND followed by an number. example:

`"hello world.foo 1.1 bar.1"` ==> `["hello world","foo 1.1 bar", "1"]`

I currently have:

```
"(?<![0-9])\.(?!\d)"
```

but it gives:

```
["hello world", "foo 1.1 bar.1"]
```

but its not finding the last `"."` valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on `.` if it is not preceded by a digit, or if it is not succeeded by a digit:

```
In [18]: re.split(r'(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)', text)
Out[18]: ['hello world', 'foo 1.1 bar', '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

A non-| approach:

```
(?<![0-9](?=.[0-9]))\.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because only one of those assertions have to fail for the whole expression to fail. Try this:

```
"(?<![0-9])\.|\.(?!\d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of contributing the shortest solution, here is mine:

(it is simply @ysth's solution with a small adjustment)

`(?<!\d(?=.\d))\.`

[working fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/duW7M8/2)